# AWS DMS Exporting Bad CSV Rows When String Field Ends in Backslash

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-dms

I recently set up an RDS Postgres -> DMS -> S3 migration task. We are then using Snowpipe to import the CSV files from S3 into Snowflake. The issue I'm having is that DMS will automatically enclose certain string column values in double quotes when there are problematic characters, but we are getting a number of rows that have no problematic characters aside from the fact that they end with a backslash. Here is an example row:

```
613553630,1593721266,51801497,40223361753,Im definetly a traitor 100% confirmed  PC /  PW  Partner  -  !discord  ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ --\,,2022-09-17 19:01:58.000000,2022-09-17 19:01:58.000000,true,en,archive,14671,false,2022-09-19 03:11:59.961644,2022-09-19 03:11:59.961645
```

Rows like this fail on import to Snowflake because the column delimiter comma is being treated as part of the string due to the trailing backslash.

Is there a way, either through the S3 destination endpoint settings, or a transformation rule, to tell DMS to always enclose every string for this column in double quotes? Is there some other way to solve this anyone can think of on the DMS side? Alternatively, does anyone know of a strategy to deal with this on the import side with the Snowflake `COPY INTO`?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - can’t you just use the ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD parameter in your COPY INTO statement?

Comment: @NickW I think this is working thank you! When I first read the description for that parameter I couldn't quite understand what it meant. After playing with it importing into a test table, I think it's doing exactly what I need it to do. To translate what the docs say for ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD, this parameter will set the escape character exclusively on string fields that are not enclosed in double quotes. Since DMS seems to be enclosing everything requiring an escape character in double quotes, I set the param to `NONE` in my file format. This is allowing the files to import successfully.

Comment: The answer above fixed the issue for me, however I'm not going to mark this as resolved just yet because I'm still curious if anyone knows how to do this on the DMS side, and if they do, the answer may help others.

Comment: Yes we are facing the same issue on the DMS side and i'd love to know if everyone ever found a solution. I am working on it right now, i'll let you know if i find something.